# select rows based on column and preserve dimension in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do the following: on a dataframe `X`, I want to select all rows where `X['a']>0` but I want to preserve the dimension of `X`, so that any other row will appear as containing `NaN`. Is there a fast way to do it? If one does `X[X['a']>0]` the dimensions of `X` are not preserved.

Comment: `X.loc[X['a']>0] = pd.np.nan` works, i guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double subscript `[[]]`:

```
In [42]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(10)})
df

Out[42]:
          a
0  1.042971
1  0.978914
2  0.764374
3 -0.338405
4  0.974011
5 -0.995945
6 -1.649612
7  0.965838
8 -0.142608
9 -0.804508

In [48]:
df[df[['a']] > 1]

Out[48]:
          a
0  1.042971
1       NaN
2       NaN
3       NaN
4       NaN
5       NaN
6       NaN
7       NaN
8       NaN
9       NaN
```

The key semantic difference here is what is returned is a df when you double subscript so this masks the df itself rather than the index

Note though that if you have multiple columns then it will mask all those as `NaN`

Comment: thank you! I never knew about the double subscript thing!

Comment: @EdChum - incase of DataFrame (with multiple columns), all the row elements are not made NaN, I suspect? Only, the filtered column would be set to NaN

Comment: @JohnGalt yes I added this, I don't know what the OP's real df actually is like so there are multiple ways around this

Comment: @JohnGalt you could either set to `NaN` as you suggested but you then still need to `concat` anyway